# How to calculate kernel dimensions from original image dimensions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/blob/master/models/resnet.py

From reading https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html the cifar dataset consists of images each with 32x32 dimension.

My understanding of code :

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
self.fc1   = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
```

Is :

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5) # 3 channels in, 6 channels out ,  kernel size of 5
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5) # 6 channels in, 16 channels out ,  kernel size of 5
self.fc1   = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120) # 16*5*5 in features , 120 ouot feature
```

From resnet.py the following :

```
self.fc1   = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
```

From http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ the following is stated :

> Summary. To summarize, the Conv Layer:
>
> Accepts a volume of size W1×H1×D1 Requires four hyperparameters:
>   Number of filters K, their spatial extent F, the stride S, the amount
>   of zero padding P. Produces a volume of size W2×H2×D2 where:
>   W2=(W1−F+2P)/S+1 H2=(H1−F+2P)/S+1 (i.e. width and height are computed
>   equally by symmetry) D2=K With parameter sharing, it introduces F⋅F⋅D1
>   weights per filter, for a total of (F⋅F⋅D1)⋅K weights and K biases. In
>   the output volume, the d-th depth slice (of size W2×H2) is the result
>   of performing a valid convolution of the d-th filter over the input
>   volume with a stride of S, and then offset by d-th bias.

From this I'm attempting to understand how the training image dimension 32x32 (1024 pixels) is transformed to feature map (16*5*5 -> 400) as aprt of `nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)`

From https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d can see default stride is 1 and padding is 0.

What are steps to arrive at 16*5*5 from image dimension of 32*32 and can 16*5*5 be derived from above steps ?

From above steps how to calculate `spatial extent` ?

Update :

Source code :

```
'''LeNet in PyTorch.'''
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class LeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1   = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2   = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3   = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        out = F.max_pool2d(out, 2)
        out = F.relu(self.conv2(out))
        out = F.max_pool2d(out, 2)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
        out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
        out = self.fc3(out)
        return out
```

Taken from https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar/blob/master/models/lenet.py

My understanding is that the convolution operation is applied to the image data per kernel. So if 5 kernels are set then 5 convolutions are applied to the data which generates a 5 dimensional image representation.

Comment: you need to look at the code implementing `forward` pass: it seems like you omit pooling layers and maybe some other stuff that may affect the size of the receptive field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide enough information in your question (see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044361/how-to-calculate-kernel-dimensions-from-original-image-dimensions#comment91050946_52044361)).

However, if I have to guess then you have two pooling layers (with stride 2) in between your convolution layers:

- input size 32x32 (3 channels)
- `conv1` output size 28x28 (6 channels): conv with no padding and kernel size 5, reduces input size by 4.
- Pooling layer with stride 2, output size 14x14 (6 channels).
- `conv2` output size 10x10 (16 channels)
- Another pooling layer with stride 2, output size 5x5 (16 channels)
- A fully connected layer (`nn.Linear`) connecting all 5x5x16 inputs to all 120 outputs.

A more thorough guide for estimating the receptive field can be found [here](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807).

Comment: @blue-sky your update validates my guess: there are indeed two pooling layers with stride 2. Does my post now answer your question?

Comment: thanks for answering, pity the questions has so many downvotes. I think i need to learn more about this area.